# SASS -scss background-image link

Tags: html, css, sass

I try to create a Full Screen Image Slider for a project with sass 
the slider is suppose to appear for the mobile version 
on half of the screen :
[image]

the html is like this :

```html
        <div id="slideShow"class="wrap">
            <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow"></div>
            <div id="slider">
                <div class="slide slide1">
                    <div class="slide-content" >
                        <span>Image One</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide slide2">
                    <div class="slide-content">
                        <span>Image Two</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide slide3">
                    <div class="slide-content">
                        <span>Image Three</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide slide4">
                    <div class="slide-content">
                        <span>Image Four</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
```

and my scss file look like this :

```css
#background{


    .wrap{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vh;
        overflow: hidden;

        .slide{
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color: none;

            .slide1{background-image: url('../../img/photo/32205901_10216113101158488_4707111253917564928_n.jpg')}
            .slide2{background-image: url('../../img/photo/27748300_10213965746245449_4810004832094893115_o.jpg')}
            .slide3{background-image: url('../../img/photo/23905655_10155338212644615_4950099036934162252_n.jpg')}
        }
    }
```

but the image don't load i don't know why if someone has a better way to do it thanks a lot

Comment: I ca not see any htnl with `id="background"` as you use in css `#background`

Comment: `.wrap` isn't a child of `#background` and `.slide` isn't a child of `.wrap`.. `.slide` is in fact a child of `.slider`. You should open developer tools and inspect the styles to see if you're getting the correct results applied to given elements.

Comment: sorry the Id background  his above the fullslide show

Comment: the code is more like this :

Answer (score 0):

`slide1` not child of `slide` so move the close `}` to close `slide{}` then style `.slide1..`

[See working code](https://jsfiddle.net/mvL0qg6z/)

```
.wrap{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vh;
        overflow: hidden;

   .slide{
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color: none;
      } /* close here the .slide then style silde1\2\3 */
            .slide1{background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg')}
            .slide2{background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg')}
            .slide3{background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg')}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

slide1 is not a child of class slide, you can target elements with two classes like this in sass:

```
.slide{ 
  /*general styles for slide, like background, ..*/
  &.slide1 {
    /*styles that should apply to .slide.slide1*/
    background-image: ....;
  }
  &.slide2 {
    /*same for slide 2*/
  }
```

Comment: i try but its seem the url link still don't work the picture steel not appear

Comment: @matthiasscreed You would have to checkt the network tab in your browser and see from where the images are loaded. Most probably it's just the path that's wrong. BTW try  to avoid using relative paths, use absolute paths.